# jQuery UI Datepicker beforeShowDay - Enable the day after the one that is tested

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm fighting with the beforeShowDay event :

The datepicker I'm setting up proposes starting dates for some study programs and it needs to behave this way :

- For some courses, starting dates are pre-defined dates, I got this part working fine.
- For some other programs I need only Mondays to be available (this is done), but if Monday is a holiday, I disable it. (This is also working fine for me).
  The only thing I miss is that I'd like not only to disable this Monday but also to enable the following Tuesday (that was supposed to be disabled at first as I only wanted Mondays to be selectable).

Here is what I did so far (probably not optimized, but I'll see what I can do once everything is up and running) :

```
function availableDays(date) {
    var holidays = $("#holidays").text(); // "1-1-2012,2-20-2012,4-6-2012,4-9-2012,5-21-2012,7-2-2012,8-6-2012,9-3-2012-10-8-2012,11-11-2012,12-25-2012,12-26-2012"
    var holidaysDates = new Array();
    holidaysDates = holidays.split(",");

    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();

    var selectedCourseStartingDates = $("#courseName option:selected").attr("startingdates");
    if(selectedCourseStartingDates != "") {
        var courseStartingDates = new Array();
        courseStartingDates = selectedCourseStartingDates.split(",");

        for(i = 0; i < courseStartingDates.length; i++) {
            if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,courseStartingDates) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
                if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,holidaysDates) != -1) {
                    return [false];
                }
                else {
                    return [true];
                }
            }
            else {
                return [false];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // If not Monday
        if(date.getDay() != 1) {
            return [false];
        }
        else {
            if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,holidaysDates) != -1) {
                return [false];
            }
            else {
                return [true];
            }
        }
    }
}

function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return noWeekend[0] ? availableDays(date) : noWeekend;
}
```

And I call "noWeekendsOrHolidays" on the beforeShowDay event.
I get my dates from a 2 strings (specific enabled days and holidays to desable) in this format "m-d-yyyy".

I need your help to find out where in this loop (and how if it is actually possible) I could tell the datepicker instance to return true or false for the date after the once that is currently being tested ?

Is it possible when I hit a holiday Monday, to put a flag so on the next iteration (next day on the calendar) the test could take this flag into consideration to return true for a Tuesday instead of false as it was supposed to behave in the first place ?

Well, I hope I was clear enough ? English is not my native language so let me know if some terms I used are not the right ones.

Thanks a lot for your help on this !

Cédric

Answer (score 0):

Posting my issue right here actually allowed me to stand back and find the solution.

Here is my updated code :

```
function availableDays(date) {
    var holidays = $("#holidays").text(); // "1-1-2012,2-20-2012,4-6-2012,4-9-2012,5-21-2012,7-2-2012,8-6-2012,9-3-2012-10-8-2012,11-11-2012,12-25-2012,12-26-2012"
    var holidaysDates = new Array();
    holidaysDates = holidays.split(",");

    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();

    var selectedCourseStartingDates = $("#courseName option:selected").attr("startingdates");
    if(selectedCourseStartingDates != "") {
        var courseStartingDates = new Array();
        courseStartingDates = selectedCourseStartingDates.split(",");

        for(i = 0; i < courseStartingDates.length; i++) {
            if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,courseStartingDates) != -1 || new Date() > date) {
                if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,holidaysDates) != -1) {
                    return [false];
                }
                else {
                    return [true];
                }
            }
            else {
                return [false];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // If not Monday
        if(date.getDay() != 1) {
            /* UPDATED */
            if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + (d-1) + '-' + y,holidaysDates) != -1) {
                return [true];
            }
            else {
                return [false];
            }
            /**********/
        }
        else {
            if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,holidaysDates) != -1) {
                return [false];
            }
            else {
                return [true];
            }
        }
    }
}

function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
    var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    return noWeekend[0] ? availableDays(date) : noWeekend;
}
```

I simply test the day before (d-1) when I hit a holiday that is not a Monday.

Have a nice day !

Cédric